# W7: Clean up before go to stand by

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have the problem that I need to clean up some things, before the standby mode will be entered.
The problem is, that I also need to do this, when the customers presses the power button (if configured to go to sleep mode).

```
PowerSetRequest(_PowerRequest, PowerRequestType.PowerRequestAwayModeRequired);
```

Is not working for this, the computer directly goes to sleep.

I also tried this with

```
SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED );
```

But it also failed.

Has someone any hint for me?

Answer (score 1):

The following quote from [SetThreadExecutionState function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests that this is no longer possible:

> The SetThreadExecutionState function cannot be used to prevent the
>   user from putting the computer to sleep. Applications should respect
>   that the user expects a certain behavior when they close the lid on
>   their laptop or press the power button.

Comment: Thank's for the answer - you are right, what I found is what is described here.

My problem was:
Sometimes I have some connections to a server and I ether need to postpone the standby mode until this transaction is finished (I would say this time is always below 10 seconds). Also I tried to offer the customer the capability to cancel the transaction and then go directly to standby.